# How to interpolate within a string?

Tags: angular, interpolation

What is the Angular2 way for interpolating multiple variables (from a class) in a situation like the following?

```html
<img alt="" src="/images/{{userName}}/{{year}}/{{nameOfImage}}.jpg" />
```

my `component.ts` class looks like this:

```ts
export class EditorsChoiceComponent {

  userName = 'Black Ranger';
  year = 'sometimeinthe90s';
  nameOfImage = 'gogopowerrangers'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough to do it in the class using a [template string](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string) and an [accessor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors):

```ts
export class EditorsChoiceComponent {
  userName = 'Black Ranger';
  year = 'sometimeinthe90s';
  nameOfImage = 'gogopowerrangers';

  get imageSrc() {
    return `/images/${this.userName}/${this.year}/${this.nameOfImage}.jpg`;
  }
}
```

The binding can be a simple [property binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding) rather than interpolation:

```
<img alt="" [src]="imageSrc" />
```

Comment: oh nice! can you explain to me what the `get` does?  do i just access this as `{{ imageSrc() }}`? why isn't the method written without the `get`?

Comment: @Moose `get` makes it an [accessor](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors)

Comment: What if you dont have that option because your information is being injected dynamically via a loop. for instance...

    `<form [formGroup]="foo_bar">
        <div formGroupName="baz_{{$i}}" *ngFor="let foo of things; let $i = index">
            <input [class.bar]="!foo_bar.get('baz_{{$i}}').valid">
            </input>
        </div>
    </form>`


comes back as got interpolation where expression was expected.

Comment: @CalebSwank why not have each item within the loop be rendered by a component that knows its own index? `<form [formGroup]="foo_bar"> <my-component *ngFor="let foo of things; let $i = index" [data]="foo" [index]="$i"></my-component></form>`.

Comment: @johnrsharpe Just kinda stumbled upon this during trial and error, but via my scenario, an easy implementation would be something like this.

`('baz_' + $i)` - didn't even cross my mind. Thanks for the help though. This could probably be implemented in the above situation similarly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Should work as you already have it:

```
<img alt="" src="/images/{{userName}}/{{year}}/{{nameOfImage}}.jpg" />
```

Example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'blue',
  template: 'Hello <img src="https://{{server}}/{{path}}" />'
})
export class BlueComponent { 
  server:string='encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com'
  path: string='images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShusMbGevCg9avhj28vFlBQsUlv49OFoXWUDyHmZOawWZUEm0L0TSB526d'

}
```

Demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VOMYCN3sLMsqZQxn1jAJ?p=preview

Comment: Then it's just a literal string with curly braces in, surely?

Comment: This solution gave me the following error: `Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column xx...`

Comment: Yep, just tried it; same here. Not quite what I expected!